# How to pull data from an AWS hosted DB to on-prem or Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, amazon-s3

How do I make connection to an AWS hosted database, and pull or query data into a local or Azure hosted SQL server DB? Can I be directed to the right place or resource?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about the fact that they're in AWS or Azure VMs. For this to work, you need TCP/IP connectivity from your client to the server, and you need port 1433 to not be blocked along the way.

The VM in AWS or Azure needs to have an externally visible IP address, or you need to be connecting via a VPN to the internal network of the cloud-hosted system. The operating system on that VM that's hosting SQL Server needs to have a firewall rule that allows port 1433 inbound.

Once you can do that, you can then just set up a Linked Server on your end, that refers to the SQL Server at the other end. That will allow you to query the tables on the server via 4 part names i.e. linkedservername.databasename.schemaname.tablename.

If you have SQL Server with the same collation at both ends, also ensure you set "collation compatible" on the linked server configuration. (It can make a huge performance difference)